# How to Make PHP/SQL Query to Select Rows Where Column Doesn't Equal Variable

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, row, where-clause

I am trying to make a Query for an MSSQL table using PHP that will find rows with a column that doesn't equal a certain value.

I am currently using this:

```
  $selecting6 = "select * from used_trailers1 where photo1='".$picature2."' or photo='".$picature2."' or name='".$picature2."' or photo2='".$picature2."' or photo3='".$picature2."' or photo4='".$picature2."' and Orderid isnot '".$id."'";
```

To no avail, this code doesn't work.

What proper code can be used to select rows that don't have the value of `$id`?

Thank you for any help. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$selecting6 = "select * from used_trailers1 where (photo1='".$picature2."' or photo='".$picature2."' or name='".$picature2."' or photo2='".$picature2."' or photo3='".$picature2."' or photo4='".$picature2."') and Orderid !='".$id."'";
```

Comment: I am accepting your answer because I used it first, and it works.

Comment: @Kelsey glad that your problem fixed

Answer (score 1):

Not equal operator in SQL standard is `<>` But MySQL and SQL Server also support `!=`. Read [Comparison Operators in SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx) [Comparison Functions and Operators in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html).

```
SELECT [*] FROM [tbl] WHERE id <> $id
```

Comment: I Edited My answer. But `<>` is standard in SQL.